# "expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '{' token" in Struct member function

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, struct, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get my prof's overengineered C++ code to compile. This is the code I have:

```
/**
 * Vector class.
 * Common mathematical operations on vectors in R3.
 *
 * Written by Robert Osada, March 1999.
 **/
#ifndef __VECTOR_H__
#define __VECTOR_H__

/**
 * Vector3
 **/
struct Vector3f
{
  // coordinates
  float x, y, z;

  // norm
  float      normSquared () { return x*x+y*y+z*z; }
  double norm        () { return sqrt(normSquared()); }

  // boolean operators
  bool operator == (const Vector3f& v) const { return x==v.x && y==v.y && z==v.z; }
  bool operator != (const Vector3f& v) const { return x!=v.x || y!=v.y || z!=v.z; }

  // operators
  Vector3f  operator +  (const Vector3f &v) const { return Vector3f(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z); }
  Vector3f& operator += (const Vector3f &v)       { x+=v.x; y+=v.y; z+=v.z; return *this; }
  Vector3f  operator -  () const                 { return Vector3f(-x, -y, -z); }
  Vector3f  operator -  (const Vector3f &v) const { return Vector3f(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z); }
  Vector3f& operator -= (const Vector3f &v)       { x-=v.x; y-=v.y; z-=v.z; return *this; }
  Vector3f  operator *  (float s) const              { return Vector3f(x*s, y*s, z*s); }
  Vector3f& operator *= (float s)                { x*=s; y*=s; z*=s; return *this; }
  Vector3f  operator /  (float s) const          { assert(s); return (*this)* (1/s); }
  Vector3f& operator /= (float s)                { assert(s); return (*this)*=(1/s); }

 // create a vector
 Vector3f (float x_=0, float y_=0, float z_=0) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) {};

 // set coordinates
 void set (float x_, float y_, float z_) { x=x_; y=y_; z=z_; }
};

inline float Dot (const Vector3f& l, const Vector3f r)
{
  return l.x*r.x + l.y*r.y + l.z*r.z;
}

// cross product
inline Vector3f Cross (const Vector3f& l, const Vector3f& r)
{
  return Vector3f(
    l.y*r.z - l.z*r.y,
    l.z*r.x - l.x*r.z,
    l.x*r.y - l.y*r.x );
}

#include "Misc.h"
/*
inline Vector3f Min (const Vector3f &l, const Vector3f &r)
{
  return Vector3f(Min(l.x,r.x), Min(l.y,r.y), Min(l.z,r.z));
}

inline Vector3f Max (const Vector3f &l, const Vector3f &r)
{
  return Vector3f(Max(l.x,r.x), Max(l.y,r.y), Max(l.z,r.z));
}
*/
#endif
```

and I'm getting the error on the line which defines normSquared(). It seems to give an error regardless of which method comes first in the struct. Does any have any suggestions?

Comment: This code compiles fine for me (Visual C++ 2008). What compiler are you using?

Comment: It's likely that the actual error is before this code.

Comment: Since this is tagged `objective-c++`, are we to assume you're trying to compile this C++ code with an Objective-C++ compiler?

Comment: I'm using XCode 3.2. g++ -dumpversion gives 4.2.1. I'll edit the post to include the full file.

Comment: I'm also getting "expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token" on the first inline function and "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Cross'" on the second inline function.

Comment: I tried compiling with g++ from the command line, and there is no issue here. Could this be an XCode-specific thing?

Comment: It compiles OK under Comeau: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to compile with a C compiler maybe? If you try to compile your C++ code with a C only compiler I think you would get those type of messages.

Comment: I think this might have been it; I doubled-checked and got XCode to use the cpp compiler, but still got the error.

Comment: Turns out if you include a C++ file from a strictly Objective-C file (something .m), then it appears to use the Obj-C compiler. I renamed my view controller to have a .mm extension, and everything worked fine. Frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Your inline functions miss their class scope specifiers: No `Vector3f::`.

For example:

```
inline float Vector3f::Dot (const Vector3f& l, const Vector3f r)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't address the first compiler error. I've tried just creating an empty struct with an empty method, and I still get the same thing. It seems to compile with g++, but not in XCode. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Dot and Cross are not member functions in the above struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve the compiler errors, so I just rewrote the methods as static inline methods. By taking out everything from the struct, I managed to get it to work. The operator overloadings I just dropped because they weren't actually used anywhere else in the project. (I said it was overengineered).

Thanks for all who answered!