# How do you compile structs with member functions with Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, struct, compiler-errors, android-ndk-r5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before '{' token” in Struct member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247615/expected-or-attribute-before-token-in-struct-memb)

Im compiling a C++ library with android ndk-build. I get compilation errors when the code has a struct with a member function defined in it. 
This code compiles with other compilers.

Sample code:

```
typedef struct
{
    boolean current;
    int a;
    boolean IsCurrent() const
    {
      return current;
    }
} sampleStruct;
```

The error i get is - 
" error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before 'const'"
if i get rid of const, the error is - 
" error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before '{' token"

Comment: Which C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: boolean should probably be bool !!

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Replace `boolean` with `bool`, because that's C++' boolean-type.
2. Make sure you are not compiling with a C compiler.

Style advice:
Note that `typedef struct { ... } name;` is an obsolete practice in C++. Just write `struct name { ... };`, which enables you to write constructors and a destructor.

Comment: and pls don't forget the final `;` after the closing curly brace `}`.

Comment: @hochl: Oops, thanks. I think this roots in my mixing of english and C++, where I omitted `;` because it wasn't the end of the full expression :P

Comment: I hope you don't mind me inserting the missing `...` as well ;)

Comment: I am afraid they weren't missing, for my code being exemplary for the syntax :P But I'll leave them for your edit karma and mildness :D